# Bold incorrectly applied to Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting, bold, texworks, report

I am using the report class in TeXworks/MiKTeX and was provided with a style that is a little out of date. I am having trouble with a bold section format being transferred from a page into my Table of Contents (I want "List of Figures" to be normal in the Table of contents instead of bolded but remain bold on the page created). I could not find any examples that created the table of contents like the file I have been provided by the University.

[image: List of Figures should not be in bold]

```
    \def\contentsname{\bf{Table of Contents}}
    \def\tableofcontents{\@restonecolfalse\if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
     \fi\chapter*{\contentsname
      \@mkboth{{\contentsname}}{{\contentsname}}
      }
     {\doublespacing\@starttoc{toc}}\if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi}

    \def\listfigurename{\bf{List of Figures}}
    \def\listoffigures{\@restonecolfalse\if@twocolumn\@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
     \fi\chapter*{\listfigurename\@mkboth
     {{\listfigurename}}{{\listfigurename}}}
     \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
      {\@starttoc{lof}}\if@restonecol
     \twocolumn\fi}
```

Later in the .tex

```
    \tableofcontents
    \listoftables
    \listoffigures
```

I can provide more of my code if it is needed.

Comment: `\def\listfigurename{\bf{List of Figures}}`  is wrong: the \xxxxname macros should just be text, since bold face has been added there then all uses of the text will be bold,. (`\bf` shouldn't be used at all, but that's a different matter)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than rely on macros which you yourself consider to be "a little out of date", you may to employ the capabilities of the `tocbibind` and `tocloft` packages to achieve your formatting objectives.

Incidentally, `\bf` is a plain-TeX macro whose use is deprecated under LaTeX. At any rate, `\bf` does not take an argument; if you must use it, write `{\bf List of Figures}` rather than `\bf{List of Figures}`.

Here's a sample implementation of the screenshot you've posted that uses the `tocbibind` and `tocloft` packages.

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind} % Don't include ToC line in ToC

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}
\renewcommand\cfttoctitlefont{\hfil\mdseries} % use "\bfseries" if you want it in bold
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{\hfil}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\mdseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\mdseries}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{-1} % no numbers for chapters, sections, etc

\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Abstract}
\chapter{Acknowledgments}
\lipsum[1-7]  % filler text

\clearpage
\listoftables

\clearpage
\listoffigures

\clearpage
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Scope and Objectives}

\chapter{Literature Review}

\end{document}
```